# Create a MethodInfo that is static from a reflected MethodInfo that is an instance method

Tags: c#, .net, static-methods, system.reflection, instance-methods

Assume you have an dynamic library and you want to collect all its methods via `System.Reflection` namespace.
Now, if a method is an instance method, you want to:

- load it via reflection
- convert it into a static method, whose signature contains one more input parameter of the type of the declaring instance.
  The conversion below summarises the second point, but I am having troubles with that.
  Problems are two:

  1. The return of `Delegate.CreateDelegate(delegateType, method).Method` has the correct arguments, but the method is not `static`.
  2. Sometimes it fails to bind the method, although the parameters are correct:

     System.ArgumentException
     "Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type."

The method is below:

```
    public static MethodInfo ToStatic(this MethodInfo method)
    {
        MethodInfo staticmethod;
        if (method.IsStatic)
            return method;

        List<Type> parametersTypes = method.GetParameters().Select(x => x.ParameterType).ToList();
        parametersTypes.Insert(0, method.DeclaringType);
        parametersTypes.Add(method.ReturnType);

        Type delegateType = Expression.GetDelegateType(parametersTypes.ToArray());

        staticmethod = Delegate.CreateDelegate(delegateType, method).Method;

        return staticmethod.IsStatic ? staticmethod : null;
    }
```

Is there any way to force create a `Delegate` whose method is `static`?
If so, what `static class` would hold that method?

Comment: I don't follow the premise of the question. An instance method needs to be called on an instance; a static method doesn't. If you convert an instance method to a static method, what instance will it be called on?

Comment: As in the `ToStatic` example, the correspondent `static` method would contain one more parameter, whose type is the `method.DeclaringType`.

Comment: Right - that bit is commented out, and instead you add `method.ReturnType`, which I don't understand

Comment: Yes, apologise, I just corrected the code and added some comments

Comment: Ultimately, I don't think this is possible (without resorting to something like Reflection.Emit). The method you're calling is always going to be an instance method -- you can't change that. You can't wrap it in a static method without capturing some state (e.g. the underlying MethodInfo to invoke).

Comment: Can we take a step back -- why are you trying to do this? What are you trying to actually achieve? Why do you are whether `delegate.Method.IsStatic` is true or false?

Comment: `Delegate.CreateDelegate` asks for that kind of signature: declaring type, method parameters, return type.
For a bigger picture, the constraint is for compliance to an external library. It is asking for static methods to expose, and instance methods to crash it.

Comment: It would be easy to create an *instance* method whose signature contains one more input parameter of the type of the declaring instance -- `(object[] parameters) => methodInfo.Invoke(parameters[0], parameters.Skip(1).ToArray())`. Would that work?

Comment: The question was _what are you trying to do with the result of `Delegate.CreateDelegate`_. Let's assume the call of `Delegate.CreateDelegate` returns a valid `MethodInfo`. What are you doing with this object?

Comment: Right, so it is being fed to an external library, that exposes it into a visual programming environment. Ultimately what that does it, compiling it, and calling it. The reason for doing the above is that I don't think there are ways around it that do not required modifying the external library.